# SQLAlchemy User Defined Function Error

Tags: python-2.7, sqlalchemy, user-defined-functions

I'm attempting to call a user defined function (table function) using SQLAlchemy. Here is my code:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

db = create_engine('mssql+pymssql://User:Password@Server/Database')

metadata = MetaData(db)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=db)
session = Session()

results = session.query(func.MyFunctionName('Value')).all()
```

When this executes I get the following error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (OperationalError) (195,
>   "'MyFunctionName' is not a recognized built-in function name.DB-Lib
>   error message 195, severity 15:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check
>   messages from the SQL Server\n") 'SELECT
>   MyFunctionName(%(MyFunctionName_2)s) AS [MyFunctionName_1]'
>   {'MyFunctionName_2': 'Value'}

When I look at SQL Profiler, I get the following:

> SELECT MyFunctionName('Value') AS [MyFunctionName_1]

Which tells me that it is not adding the **SELECT * FROM MyFunctionName** in the query.

What do I need to do to get my session.query to add the * FROM in the query for execution?

If you need more information, please leave a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a table based function you need to turn into a select() object first, using the pattern described at http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#functions

```
myfunc = select([column('x'), column('y')]).select_from(func.myfunction())
session.execute(myfunc).fetchall()
```

Comment: This worked with tweaking. I had to change session.query to session.execute(myfunc).fetchall(). I edited your response with the updated code.

Comment: passing the select() to query() should work as well, it will wrap it in an extra SELECT but you'll still get the same result.  what was your output/version of SQLAlchemy ?

Comment: It appears I need an alias for my wrapped sub select. So "select column from (select column from myfunc()) as A